# SassError: Unexpected identifier. Updated Primeflex v2 to v3 and got errors in compilation of primeflex

Tags: angular, sass, sass-loader, primeflex

```
Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass- 
loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Expected identifier.
   ╷
27 │         .text-blue #007bff{
   │                     ^
   ╵
node_modules\primeflex\src\_mixins.scss 27:21  color-class()
node_modules\primeflex\src\_colors.scss 11:1   @import
node_modules\primeflex\primeflex.scss 4:9      @import
src\styles.scss 17:9                           root stylesheet
```

I recently upgraded my angular 11 project to angular 13 and upgraded Primeflex v2 to primeflex v3. While I serve my application I get this error.

[image]

My Primeng Versions in Package.json
[image]

I upgraded Angular to its latest version too.
Have any of you faced similar errors?
Do you have any solution to this?